# Excel Using Reference for Worksheet names

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I've looked around to try and resolve this, however I am unfamiliar with the coding.

Here's my line of code,

```
='[WorkBook]BOM'!G6
```

What I want to do is make the Workbook call to a cell so I can mass replace all the 'Workbook' names without Find and Replace.

Essentially, something like this (Though this code does not work, it is just for reference)

```
='[=E1]BOM'!G6
```

Then in cell E1, I would be able to enter any text I want, to replace the Workbooks name.
I'm trying to find the Formula to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `INDIRECT()` function to evaluate a text string as a function.

```
=INDIRECT("'["& E1 & "]BOM'!G6")
```

Note that the `INDIRECT()` function will only return the value if the referenced workbook is open. Otherwise it will return a `#REF!`-error.

Comment: I tried implementing this code into my excel sheet, as did one of my co-workers into theirs. Neither of us received results, as we both came up with #REF!

The WorkBook I'm referencing is open as well. Thanks for the fast response, however.

Comment: As noted, this might be because the workbook you are referencing to are closed. This is the closest you would come such a solution without using VBA.

Comment: What does "Evaluate Formula" tell you?

Comment: note also that it will expect the full name - `workbook` would not work, you would have to put `workbook.xlsx` - If the file is closed, you would need the full pathname: `C:\Users\MyName\Documents\workbook.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` will not work with closed outside workbooks. Your best bet at automation seems to be to put the workbook path in a cell, and write a macro that will find/replace all the occurrences of the old workbook name and replace with the new workbook name.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would let you reference a range, only if you name them first.

For example you name the range A1:A100 as MyRange in Workbook 1

Then in your current Workbook you can enter "MyRange" in E1 in Workbook 2

then use INDIRECT(E1)